# Send terminal output of software to file or /dev/null

Tags: shell, io-redirection, dev-null

I'm working with a program called Velvet (what we call an assembler in bioinformatics). This software doesn't come with a silent or quiet mode option and I have a script that runs it several times causing it to saturate my terminal with text that isn't really meaningful to me in that moment (about 100 lines of text are printed per iteration).

I have tried to send this output to `/dev/null` by doing this:

```
[Terminal@Session]$ velvet -option1 -option2 -file1 -file2 > /dev/null
```

However this causes the shell to complain about a segmentation fault and the software doesn't actually run at all. I feel like this is a syntax problem since trying to send the stuff to `/dev/null` like I did might interfere with the expected software syntax and hence the error appears. I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. Is there any other syntax I can use to redirect the output?

Comment: You know about `stderr`, that can be redirected too? I do not understand the seg. fault, do you also have this with `velvet -option1 -option2 -file1 -file2 > /tmp/velvet1.out 2>/tmp/velvet2.out` ?

Comment: Running with `strace` might provide some hints as to where in the program the problem is and therefor how to work around it.

Comment: What OS and shell are you using? Can you share the exact command you ran?

Comment: Your method is working @WalterA, could you post it as answer? just to complement I am on Debian GNU/Linux 9, my shell is GNU bash 4.4.12(1). My command when the segfault happened was `velveth test 31 -fastq.gz -shortPaired -separate R1.fastq.gz R2.fastq.gz > /dev/null`

Comment: I've found that velvet does this in it's own testing. https://github.com/dzerbino/velvet/blob/master/tests/interleaved_eq_separate.t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP confirmed that my proposal in a comment worked, even without knowing why.
You can redirect output to 'normal' files with

```
velvet -option1 -option2 -file1 -file2 > /tmp/velvet1.out 2>/tmp/velvet2.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is fine. Velvet is crashing, which isn't the shell's fault. It's strange and unfortunate that it runs differently when output is redirected versus when it's sent to the terminal, but it's not your doing. It's rare for programs to care where stdout is redirected. `> /dev/null` is safe for 99+% of the programs out there. (Sometimes stderr also needs to be redirected, but that's a different topic.)

Does Velvet have a command-line option for quieter output? Many programs have `-q` or `--quiet` or something similar.

Comment: Dang, so if this is true then I assume there is nothing that can be done D: It doesn't come with a quiet option unfortunately